# Custom Regular Expression in Java

Tags: android, regex

I have to implement a function that check if a string is compliant to a regular expression, I have wrote a method that parse a list of filename, for each file name I need to check if respect the regexp.

The filename is composed like as follow (just an example):

- verbale.pdf.001.001
- image.jpg.002.001

The string is always composed by:

**extension** (only jpg or pdf) "**.**" **a group of three number** "**.**" **a group of three number**

With this regexp I need to check if the string in input end as described above, I have currently implemented this:

```
Pattern rexExp = Pattern.compile("((\\.jpg)|(\\.pdf))\\.[0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{3}");
```

But not work properly, is it a good idea implement a regExp to check if a filename end with a certain path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less greedy than the other answer, think it suits you:

```
\\w+\\.(jpg|pdf)(\\.\\d{3}){2}
```

- file name, only composed of letters, numbers and _
- dot
- jpg or pdf formats
- another dot
- three digits
- the dot and the three digits repeated

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
.*\\w{3}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}
```

.* = any Characters (like "verbale123")

\\w{3} = any 3 alphabetic\numeric characters

\\. = a dot

\\d{3} = any three numeric characters

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string ends with `pdf` or `jpg` and two sequences of `.` and 3 digits, you may use

```
(?i)(?:jpg|pdf)(?:\.[0-9]{3}){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RJ1ueF/2)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `(?:jpg|pdf)` - either `jpg` or `pdf`
- `(?:\.[0-9]{3}){2}` - 2 repetitions of a `.` and 3 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Use with `Matcher#find()` (as `matches()` anchors the match at the start and end of the string, while a partial match is required when using this pattern), [example demo](https://ideone.com/pUKZvn):

```
String s = "verbale.pdf.001.001";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:jpg|pdf)(?:\\.[0-9]{3}){2}$").matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Valid!"); 
}
```